# kubernetes expose services with Traefik 2.x as ingress with CRD

Tags: kubernetes, traefik, kubernetes-ingress, traefik-ingress

## What i have

I have a Kubernetes cluster as follow:

- Single control plane (but plan to extend to 3 control plane for HA)
- 2 worker nodes

On this cluster i deployed (following this doc from traefik https://docs.traefik.io/user-guides/crd-acme/):

- A deployment that create two pods :

  - traefik itself: which will be in charge of routing with exposed port 80, 8080
  - whoami:a simple http server thats responds to http requests
- two services

  - traefik service: [image]
  - whoami servic: [image]
- One traefik IngressRoute:
  [image]

## What i want

I have multiple services running in the cluster and i want to expose them to the outside using Ingress.
More precisely i want to use the new **Traefik 2.x** CDR ingress methods.

My ultimate goal is to use new traefiks 2.x CRD to expose resources on port 80, 443, 8080 using `IngressRoute` Custom resource definitions

## What's the problem

If i understand well, classic Ingress controllers allow exposition of every ports we want to the outside world (including 80, 8080 and 443).

But with the new traefik CDR ingress approach on it's own it does not exports anything at all.
One solution is to define the Traefik service as a loadbalancer typed service and then expose some ports. But you are forced to use the 30000-32767 ports range (same as nodeport), and i don't want to add a reverse proxy in front of the reverse proxy to be able to expose port 80 and 443...

Also i've seed from the doc of the new igress CRD (https://docs.traefik.io/user-guides/crd-acme/) that:

`kubectl port-forward --address 0.0.0.0 service/traefik 8000:8000 8080:8080 443:4443 -n default`

is required, and i understand that now. You need to map the host port to the service port.
But mapping the ports that way feels clunky and counter intuitive. I don't want to have a part of the service description in a yaml and at the same time have to remember that i need to map port with `kubectl`.

I'm pretty sure there is a neat and simple solution to this problem, but i can't understand how to keep things simple. Do you guys have an experience in kubernetes with the new traefik 2.x CRD config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after some time i've decided to put an haproxy in front of the kubernetes Cluster. It's seems to be the only solution ATM.

Answer (score 1):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: traefik

spec:
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      name: web
      port: 80
      targetPort: 8000
    - protocol: TCP
      name: admin
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
    - protocol: TCP
      name: websecure
      port: 443
      targetPort: 4443
  selector:
    app: traefik
```

have you tried to use tragetPort where every request comes on 80 redirect to 8000 but when you use port-forward you need to always use service instead of pod

Comment: I tryed that with the loadbalancer type, but not with the default type. With the loadbalancer, Kubernetes ignore those targetPort and use a random port among the 30k+ range. But even with default type i feel like it's not going to work, because with this config no ports are expose to the outside, the trick you are mentionning is just about inner cluster communication right?

Comment: by default kubernetes loadbalancer  type use NodePort for communication if you want to change default ports assign by kubernetes which in rage of 30k+ you have to do modification in kubernters api. and assign there your desired range

Comment: i know about this solution but i don't like it either, that is aditional in place configuration that i will forgoet about in less than a week, and i will enrage trying to troubleshoot when the system is going to fail. The more i read about that the more i think that using a regular Nginx Ingress in front of the traefik CRD is the way to go

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use LoadBalancer service type for expose the Traefik service on ports 80, 443 and 8080. I've tested the yaml from the link you provided in GKE, and it's works.

You need to change the ports on 'traefik' service and add a 'LoadBalancer' as service type:

```
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: traefik
spec:
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      name: web
      port: 80 <== Port to receive HTTP connections
    - protocol: TCP
      name: admin
      port: 8080 <== Administration port
    - protocol: TCP
      name: websecure
      port: 443 <== Port to receive HTTPS connections
  selector:
    app: traefik
  type: LoadBalancer <== Define the type load balancer
```

Kubernetes will create a Loadbalancer for you service and you can access your application using ports 80 and 443.

```
$ curl https://35.111.XXX.XX/tls -k
Hostname: whoami-5df4df6ff5-xwflt
IP: 127.0.0.1
IP: 10.60.1.11
RemoteAddr: 10.60.1.13:55262
GET /tls HTTP/1.1
Host: 35.111.XXX.XX
User-Agent: curl/7.66.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip
X-Forwarded-For: 10.60.1.1
X-Forwarded-Host: 35.111.XXX.XX
X-Forwarded-Port: 443
X-Forwarded-Proto: https
X-Forwarded-Server: traefik-66dd84c65c-4c5gp
X-Real-Ip: 10.60.1.1

$ curl http://35.111.XXX.XX/notls   
Hostname: whoami-5df4df6ff5-xwflt
IP: 127.0.0.1
IP: 10.60.1.11
RemoteAddr: 10.60.1.13:55262
GET /notls HTTP/1.1
Host: 35.111.XXX.XX
User-Agent: curl/7.66.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip
X-Forwarded-For: 10.60.1.1
X-Forwarded-Host: 35.111.XXX.XX
X-Forwarded-Port: 80
X-Forwarded-Proto: http
X-Forwarded-Server: traefik-66dd84c65c-4c5gp
X-Real-Ip: 10.60.1.1
```

Comment: Traefik on EKS, AKS and GKE need to be set as LoadBalancer and is works natively fine, but when you work on premise with (which I personally tested on ubuntu server 20.04 and 18.04) didn't seem to work properly and tracked everything here [#1414](https://github.com/k3s-io/k3s/issues/1414)

Comment: I followed the same doc mentioned in the question and got the same issue (on premise k3s). I specified the type as LoadBalancer as per your instructions and got it working.